# How long would it take until we realise that people stopped dying from natural causes?

Tags: earth, medicine, death

This would only comprise death by natural causes, no accidents, suicides, homicides etc.

As Wikipedia says:

> A death by natural causes is one that is primarily attributed to an
>   illness or an internal malfunction of the body not directly influenced
>   by external forces.  For example, a person dying from complications
>   from influenza (an infection) or a heart attack (an internal body
>   malfunction) or sudden heart failure would be listed as having died
>   from natural causes.

How long would it take until we realise that on the whole world people suddenly stopped dying by natural causes? 
(Let's say it is caused by some alien medicament that they are secretly testing on us.)

Instead of death, they are living the same as they did before this day came.

Comment: What happens instead, exactly? Coma? Magical transplant of healthy organ? Regeneration?

Comment: @Mołot question updated, is this enough?

Comment: I would say pretty rapidly as every terminally ill patient would miraculously heal overnight (and lots of miracles is always suspicious)

Comment: @Riff they would still be in this state, only the last step (death itself) would not come (and then again and again)

Comment: @TGar - does this alien medication prevent people from aging, or does the aging process continue?

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ The process continue as usual.

Comment: Suggested reading: Death at Intervals, by Jose Saramago

Comment: One of the leading causes of a heart attack is veins around the heart being clogged, and so (parts of) the heart muscle isn't supplied with blood anymore. It can't pump blood anymore -- so how in the world are you keeping a person alive that would have died of this natural cause? Or will you miraculously prevent arteriosklerosis, thrombosis, aneurisms, etc.?

Comment: @subrunner good catch, but (as you can see) after some thinking I got convinced this does not really matter for the actual answer.

Comment: @TGar They may not heal but still : when a person given 3 days to live ends up surviving a week it is suspicious ! (btw is sounds like an awful medicine, alive but in the worst state you've ever been in)

Comment: @Riff Probably true.

Comment: See also [Torchwood: Miracle Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchwood:_Miracle_Day).

Comment: @Martin Schröder I know that (and I also would recommend), but in Torchwood people don't die at all, even if they're burned to dust, that is probably quicker to find out.

Comment: @IMSoP  The USA translation is "Death With Interruptions."

Comment: @TGar: Of course. Still: Every hospital would notice very soon when their terminally ill don't die.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Of course, only if the aliens' definition of death is the same as the hospital's. It might very well be that the hospital would still proclaim them dead (e.g. due to a cessation of brain activity, even though their heart is still miraculously pumping blood or whatever). There's a reason why "natural cause" or "old age" is never written as the cause of death - it's basically saying "died, whatever; not our fault". There are always more or less proximal causes to any death, and this one isn't particularly useful. It's not like there's a switch that says "dead" and "not dead" :D

Comment: Well, no-one's yet noticed that since 1931 everyone who has died has actually been creatively and cunningly murdered.

Comment: ...oops...!  :-o

Comment: I don't think it would be quite that simple. People would still die from poison right? So if they have been consuming poison voluntarily for years and then die from that, that's suicide not natural causes. But if it was some unknown poison doctors would not know the difference.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

One day. Few at most.

In most modern countries death reports are passed to government agency on daily basis. Clerk responsible for them would be surprised that there are none in his area. He will notice sudden drop, and 0 in one category. At least some clerks would call their counterparts in adjacent areas to chit-chat about this impossible coincidence, and, with surprise, hear that the same thing happened. From this, it'll be a cascade.

The same, or next day it'll be brought to the upper seniority of government's healthcare ministers. And to the press, things like that make for really good news. And while making sure that it really is "whole world" might take a bit, I'm pretty sure it'll take well under a week for virtually everybody to know. My money is on three days for the internet-connected people.

---

Of course there is a gap between "been exposed to such information" and "actually believe this is happening". Denial and disbelief will be natural at the beginning.

Comment: I suspect this would be reported as a curious statistical quirk at first. It would take a while before anyone would believe that anything fundamental was going on.

Comment: @JackAidley on the first day, possibly. On the second one, maybe. On the third day Christians will go wild ;)

Comment: I'd say that after a week it would hit the news. After a month it would be a bonafide proof that something was wrong in the universe.

Comment: Also: doctors chat to each other about how the patients they thought were goners are hanging on for improbably long....

Comment: See [new question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66619/what-are-political-and-religious-consequences-of-the-end-of-dying) about consequences (related also with footnote edit of this answer) of discussed situation.

Comment: Great answer. Unless the magic reversed quickly fatal occurrences that already happened (everyone having a heart attack on that day were suddenly fine, everyone with ruptured appendices suddenly un-ruptured, everyone with sepsis suddenly un-sepsis'd, etc...), it would be very hard to figure this out in less time than a day or two.

Comment: When someone decides to study the timing of the sudden drop to 0, exceptions will be noted in a few locations. Outliers. A few 1's and 2's with no apparent connection between them, hours or days after the big event. These will be the murders disguised as death by natural causes.

Comment: @JackAidley Given the current death rate, a single *hour* without anybody dying by natural causes would be extremely strong evidence that the rules had changed. The nightly news might describe it as a statistical quirk, but the *statisticians* would be rushing to buy stock in birthday candle manufacturers.

Comment: @Sneftel, this is mostly a matter of communication speeds, not of statistics.  Yes, an hour without anybody dying of natural causes is a statistical impossibility, but how long does it take to gather the information to demonstrate that it happened?

Answer (score 3):

Probably after one day, people these days, keep Track of deaths. Even in Sl Salvador.
There was a newspaper article in Switzerland, that said, that there hasn't been a murder in 24 Hours in Sl Salvador. If such an event will be noticed and in the news (on the other side of the globe). If countries like El Salvador keep (that good) trak of their deaths (and why), it'll probably be the same to realize this, if it's the case from natural causes as well. Especially from "First world nations" with a preference for statistics, like the US.
This does not answer your answer directely, but shows, how good they keep track of deaths and their causes and how fast such things will be in the news aroud the world.
[image: An Article in the Swiss newspaper 20 Minuten]

Comment: Cool, nice catch. But actually tracking murders is necessary and probably the police do it. The tracking of natural causes is not so visible publically and there (mostly) is no institution for it. And that it is in the news is mainly because it is a country like El Salvador, where it is very unlikely to not have murders often. But I still see your point.

Comment: There are institutions for it. In advanced nations, there are a LOT of institutions tracking the same data separately, ranging from health to vital statistics/census offices.